# What breaking change caused my TS types to break in TS 4.7 and above (worked in v4.6)

Tags: typescript

In the codebase I am working with, I wanted to upgrade TS to the latest v4.8 version from v4.6.

For some reason I get a type error of a type that used to work properly in v4.6:

```
Parameter 'newVal' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

This parameter should actually be strictly typed and not result in type `any`.

I'm not sure what changed in v4.7+ that the types don't work anymore.

Here are the types we are using:

[TS 4.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwGoENEFcIGcoC8UAShAMYD2ATsgDy7BVwB2A5gDRTrMgB8A3AChBoSCQis4DCFQDyYYHArNctACrwkaTDigQAHsAjNk+bn0JQACuiqLMtAN6CorqAFsIwABYVkALigACgA3HQhAjQQUDGwIAEpCXigQijhkIQBfXmFRaE0UXCsqCjBaFzcorVicfAMjE3wC7TjcdgrXNQA5dE89Q2NTKABrCBAKADMoKpjw3A6oZKJnN1WoAG0rKBZpnr70fCsAXUDZdzhgcrXr8UlpOQUlFXVmmrxNo952m7WAIjC4gBBXBdLDuABGMl+UAAPlB-uFgQARdBGaFw364LxvYHo+HIKTocGICDIX4LVYCBaZITCXLgaCkO5GKjNYqlVQzFq1foNIavOZLKArNyUZiMCiISIC1pCVYTaKmQLNIolMpct5tEZjSbTGW1Kk04Rihi3KQslWWF6KzW8wZNG2CoIi1wKrRtBZiiWIdqZQJM80yNlqzn6vC8RIEZKOKBGwQm4DTACiAGU1JYA-cVc6Fm7Cv4Fi61kYGIEiz9PD4-IEgswIAB3WIARkj0djnAA9B2oHXG5gm1BcL4sCgoJCoHke2DIVQKW5Mt8biXgAAmMtz66V3wBYK92Ir1vC9tQLs9hv7wfD0fjycMJhsDex6mL1xekpSo-LwIATm-nGXa7whMFAUOCtjQpkJ7dj4UjbPg9beDI0A+MhDL4EOFAjsgUCsF42zMBMMhUKSUATCU7iCJk8RAA)

[TS 4.6](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwGoENEFcIGcoC8UAShAMYD2ATsgDy7BVwB2A5gDRTrMgB8A3AChBoSCQis4DCFQDyYYHArNctACrwkaTDigQAHsAjNk+bn0JQACuiqLMtAN6CorqAFsIwABYVkALigACgA3HQhAjQQUDGwIAEpCXigQijhkIQBfXmFRaE0UXCsqCjBaFzcorVicfAMjE3wC7TjcdgrXNQA5dE89Q2NTKABrCBAKADMoKpjw3A6oZKJnN1WoAG0rKBZpnr70fCsAXUDZdzhgcrXr8UlpOQUlFXVmmrxNo952m7WAIjC4gBBXBdLDuABGMl+UAAPlB-uFgQARdBGaFw364LxvYHo+HIKTocGICDIX4LVYCBaZITCXLgaCkO5GKjNYqlVQzFq1foNIavOZLKArNyUZiMCiISIC1pCVYTaKmQLNIolMpct5tEZjSbTGW1Kk04Rihi3KQslWWF6KzW8wZNG2CoIi1wKrRtBZiiWIdqZQJM80yNlqzn6vC8RIEZKOKBGwQm4DTACiAGU1JYA-cVc6Fm7Cv4Fi61kYGIEiz9PD4-IEgswIAB3WIARkj0djnAA9B2oHXG5gm1BcL4sCgoJCoHke2DIVQKW5Mt8biXgAAmMtz66V3wBYK92Ir1vC9tQLs9hv7wfD0fjycMJhsDex6mL1xekpSo-LwIATm-nGXa7whMFAUOCtjQpkJ7dj4UjbPg9beDI0A+MhDL4EOFAjsgUCsF42zMBMMhUKSUATCU7iCJk8RAA)

**Edit**: After simplifying the example I don't get an error, but still in v4.7+ a type which was first properly inferred is now type `unknown`. See the `TEST` const.

In v4.6 `newVal1` is inferred as type `number` and `newVal2` as type `string`. In v4.7+ both are type `unknown`.

*I already simplified the TS as much as I could, the original types are even more complex*

Comment: Well, what *are* the types that are breaking...? Oh, it's in the playground. Could you update the question and include the types, though?

Comment: I can see that this happened between [2022-03-11](https://tsplay.dev/N9nEqm) and [2022-03-17](https://tsplay.dev/mMBM6W) which means it was probably one of [these](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/search?q=merged%3A2022-03-11..2022-03-17&type=issues), but I don't know which one.  Maybe [ms/TS#478889](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47889)? I can't know more unless you either simplify your problem further or someone is willing to do their own local TS lang builds between those two dates.

Comment: Okay I've further narrowed down to being [between 2022-03-15 and 2022-03-16](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/search?q=merged%3A2022-03-15..2022-03-16&type=issues) but it still could be any of [ms/TS#48273](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48273), [ms/TS#47889](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47889), or [ms/TS#47306](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47306).  I'm not going to do more tracking than that. I'm happy to write this up as an answer, or just run away screaming.  Let me know (comment @jcalz)

Comment: @jcalz thanks for narrowing it down! Tomorrow I will take another go and trying to simplify it more. Maybe I will manage to remove some helper types and still illustrate the problem

Comment: @jcalz I was able to get all the helper types out of the way, the example should be much more simple to read now.

Comment: Actually just found the culprit. I don't know why it does not work anymore, but I was able to fix it because that type logic was not needed anymore. See answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I identified the culprit causing the types to break. I have no clue why exactly, but everything seems to work now.

The issue was caused by the following types:

```
[P in TName as P]:
```

which does not work anymore in v4.7 and needs to be

```
[P in TName]:
```

(I had it like this, because I used to exclude a type like this: `[P in TName as P extends UnacceptedPaths ? never : P]:`)

*I submitted [an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51141) on GitHub for this*